Flask nginx 404 not found in prod
I deployed my simple flask app in AWS EC2 ubuntu (it's my first time).
The home page is okay (example.com).
But if I navigate in other path (example.com/page2/) is says 404 not found.

Here are my flask code
application/_ init _.py
import os
from flask import Flask
from application.views.page1 import page1
from application.views.page2 import page2

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__) 
    app.register_blueprint(page1)
    app.register_blueprint(page2)
    return app

app = create_app()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')

application/views/page1.py:
from flask import Blueprint, redirect, url_for, render_template, jsonify, session

import flask
import datetime
import random
import math

view_name = "page1"

page1 = Blueprint(view_name, __name__)

data = {}

@page1.route('/')
def welcome():
    data['subtitle'] = ''
    return render_template('page1/index.html', data=data)

@page1.route('/'+view_name)
@page1.route('/'+view_name+'/')
def index():
    
    data['subtitle'] = ''
    return render_template('page1/index.html', data=data)

application/views/page2.py:
from flask import Blueprint, redirect, url_for, render_template, jsonify, session

import flask
import datetime
import random
import math

view_name = "page2"

page2 = Blueprint(view_name, __name__)

data = {}

@page2.route('/'+view_name)
@page2.route('/'+view_name+'/')
def index():
    
    data['subtitle'] = ''
    return render_template('page2/index.html', data=data)

And this is the nginx config:
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;  

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}


Please help on how to solve this. Please.

I would recommend that you move away from using the built in Flask web server and to something like Gunicorn. Pretty decent instructions from Digital Ocean
